# Can a WebAPI be setup as an event subscriber to a pub/sub queue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rabbitmq

I have been given a task to create a proof of concept for an ASP.NET Core C# Pub/Sub listener for all 3 (RabbitMQ, Kafka and Redis) I have all 3 working locally and can publish and subscribe to them using Console Apps (Which is what all examples I have seen online recommend)

I know WebAPI use HTTP(S) protocol and Pub/Sub tend to be WS protocol

**MY QUESTION**
Can a WebAPI alone,(Not a console and not other app) be setup as an event subscriber to a pub/sub queue ? If so, how can this be achieved  and are there any working examples ?

many thanks
Ed

Below is a working Subcriber code for RabbitMQ console app, I saw online. But as Mentioned, I want to see it working with only a WebAPI as a listener

```
using System.Text;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;



Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                     durable: false,
                     exclusive: false,
                     autoDelete: false,
                     arguments: null);

Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages.");

var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
    Console.WriteLine($" [x] Received {message}");
};
channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                     autoAck: true,
                     consumer: consumer);

Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Yes, it can. In fact, here is a Kafka example - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Web

Comment: Why would you do this? A web app is for servicing HTTP requests. Even though you certainly can (using an ASP.NET Core [hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)), there's very little benefit and a lot of negatives to forcing a web app to do tasks like processing messages off of a queue.

Comment: People in most cases should set up SignalR hubs for that kind of sub/pub pattern.